# Member variables not recommended for usage

Tags: c#, .net

According to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328263.aspx), it's not recommended to use member variables due to threading and caching. Please note that this question touches multiple fields and, while I'm certain it's primarily related to .NET/C#, it **might** turn out to be specific to CRM. It probably won't but a heads-up might be wise.

While I have a firm grasp of the problems that might arise, I'm not entirely certain I understand the **exact and precise** circumstances that are **outside** the warning's limits. The exact quotation I'm concerned with is below.

> For improved performance, Microsoft Dynamics CRM caches plug-in instances. The plug-in's Execute method should be written to be stateless because the constructor is not called for every invocation of the plug-in. Also, multiple system threads could execute the plug-in at the same time. All per invocation state information is stored in the context, so you should not use global variables or attempt to store any data in member variables for use during the next plug-in invocation unless that data was obtained from the configuration parameter provided to the constructor. Changes to a plug-ins registration will cause the plug-in to be re-initialized.

My class is build after the following principle.

```
public partial class Blopp : IPlugin
{
  private IPluginExecutionContext Context { get; set; }
  private Entity Target { get; set; }
  private IOrganizationService Service { get; set; }
  ...

  public Blopp() : this(String.Empty) { }
  public Blopp(String a) : this(a, String.Empty) { }
  public Blopp(String a, String b) { ... }

  public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
  {
    try
    {
      Assign(serviceProvider);
      DoStuff();
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
    finally { ... }
  }

  private void Assign(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) { ... }
}
```

Now, the question might see dumb but the **global variables** that are mentioned - are my **private** and **non-static** fields global somehow? I'd say they aren't but I got a bit paranoid lately and I'm trying to be humble.

Also, as I access the context and *Assign* the fields, I create a new object and assign the fields one by one (not every class has the method *Clone*). Serialization would require me to inherit the original classes and that's against requirements. Is this a sufficiently reliable approach? (Keep in mind my newly acquired paranoia.)

I've tried causing problems in my execution but as far I've seen, the issues don't arise. Of course, absence of proof isn't proof of absence. I'm only pointing out that I'm not lazy-posting. Rather aware that stuff might be wrong on a deeper level than I can see at first.

Comment: Premature optimization is the worst of evils. After paranoia that is. The MSDN article is about writing plugins for Dynamics CRM 2015, quote: `Applies To: CRM 2015 on-prem, CRM Online`. Are you creating a CRM plugin?

Comment: Are your private nonstatic objects changed during the execution of the execute method? Then you might break the "written to be stateless" rule for the method if you write a plugin for Dynamics. If not you should obey to the rules given by that system and ignore the ones for Dynamics CRM.

Comment: In my opinion it is best to do your stuff in another class and create an instance of that class in the Execute method. Your 'local' variables should be created inside that 'new' class.

Comment: @walther Yes I am. And I'm afraid that a small cutting a corner now will lead to strange and hard-to-debug problems later.

Answer (score 6):

No, private members aren't global variables. Key point being *"you should not use global variables **or** attempt to store any data in member variables for use during the next plug-in invocation"*.

It says that if you're manipulating your private (or global) variables in `Execute()`, another invocation of `Execute()` may run on the same instance at the same time and overwrite your private (or global) variables, causing code running after that to show unexpected behavior.

So, make them local variables:

```
private void Assign(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) 
{
    IPluginExecutionContext context;
    Entity target;
    IOrganizationService service;

    ...
}
```

This will ensure each call stack will access only its own variables.

Answer (score 3):

To add to CodeCaster's answer, the member variables you can have are ones initialised via the constructor(s). To avoid state though, they should be made read-only, so they are only set by the constructor:

```
public partial class Blopp : IPlugin
{
  private readonly string _a;
  private readonly string _b;

  public Blopp() : this(String.Empty) { }
  public Blopp(String a) : this(a, String.Empty) { }
  public Blopp(String a, String b) 
  {
      _a = a;
      _b = b;
  }
```

You can then safely access `_a` and `_b` from within `Execute()`

Comment: Making the variables read only of course doesn't solve the problem if the variables are mutable reference types.  If they're immutable, as well as in readonly variables, then you can rely on them remaining constant.